# A basic integration problem

Tags: integration

I am trying to integrate $$\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$. I have tried the usual methods (by parts, substitution, etc.) But they all end up making the problem even worse.

I checked online and saw that the integral contains ln. I can clearly see how the derivative is correct, but cannot understand how one would derive it.

Can anyone describe the necessary logical steps for this particular problem.

I would also be very grateful if someone could generalize the method for this particular problem!

Thanks :)

Comment: You can use the technique [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/TrigSubstitutions.aspx).

Comment: Try $t=x \sqrt{x^2-1}+ ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}) $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I would also be very grateful if someone could generalize the method for this particular problem!*

When dealing with $\sqrt{x^2\pm1}$, the obvious substitutions are either $x=\sinh t$ or $x=\cosh t$, since $\cosh^2t-\sinh^2t=1$. Also, $~\sinh't=\cosh t,$ $~\cosh't=\sinh t,$ $~\sinh2t=2\sinh t\cosh t,~$ and $\cosh2t=\sinh^2t+\cosh^2t$, etc. They are called [hyperbolic functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function), and are very similar to the trigonometric ones.

$$\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx=\int\frac{\cosh^2t}{\sinh t}\cdot\sinh t~dt=\int\cosh^2t~dt=t\cdot\cosh^2t-\underbrace{\int t\cdot\overbrace{2\cosh t\sinh t}^{\sinh2t}~dt}_I$$

$$I=t\cdot\frac{\cosh2t}2-\int\frac{\cosh2t}2dt=t\cdot\frac{\cosh2t}2-\frac{\sinh2t}4$$

Since $\cosh^2t=\dfrac{1+\cosh2t}2$ , our initial integral becomes $\displaystyle\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx=\frac t2+\frac{\sinh2t}4$, which given the fact that $~t=\cosh^{-1}x,~$ $\sinh2t=2\sinh t\cosh t,~$ $\sinh(\cosh^{-1}x)=\sqrt{x^2-1},~$ and $\cosh(\cosh^{-1}x)=x$, we finally arrive at the desired result $~\dfrac{\cosh^{-1}x+x\sqrt{x^2-1}}2$ ; $\cosh^{-1}x$ can also be re-written as $\ln\Big(x+\sqrt{x^2-1}\Big)$, since it is the inverse of $~\cosh t=\dfrac{e^t+e^{-t}}2$ , similarly to its trigonometric homologue, $\cos t=\dfrac{e^{it}+e^{-it}}2$ , see [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution) set $\displaystyle x=\sec y\implies dx=\sec y\tan y\ dy$

$$\int\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}dx=\int\frac{\sec^2y\sec y\tan y}{\tan y}\ dy=\int\sec^3y\ dy$$

Use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed)

Answer (score 1):

Try the substitution $x = \sec \theta$.